# not able to import keras for tensor flow gpu in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i am trying to import keras library after installing tensorflow gpu following the steps given in the below link,

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

and created an environment tf-gpu.

then i installed keras using pip install keras in that environment. But when i try to import keras in jupyter notebook, it gives below error,

'''

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      2 try:
----> 3     from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
      4 except ImportError:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mayank\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-88d96843a926> in <module>
----> 1 import keras

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      3     from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
      4 except ImportError:
----> 5     raise ImportError(
      6         'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. '
      7         'Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`')

ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`
```

'''

and when i check the version of tensorflow it shows '2.1.0'

Can you someone please help us with this?

Comment: remove TF 2.1 and install 2.2?

Comment: Use `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras` to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to uninstall keras and tensorflow so you get a fresh start or just create a new environment. Then install tensorflow using conda. Conda will install tensorflow 2.1.0, cuda toolkit 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.6.5. Pip does not install the toolkit or cudnn and you have to download these and change your environment path variables to point to the directories where they are stored. If you want to install tensorflow 2.2 first install tensorflow 2.1.0 with conda then use pip to install tensorflow 2.2 using pip install tensorflow ==2.2.0. Tensorflow 2.2 is compatible with the toolkit and cudnn versions installed by 2.1. Conda can install tensorflow only up to 2.1.0. Note you may want to create your new environment using python 3.7. Users have reported problems with 3.8 when installing tensorflow with conda. Tensorflow 2.0 and above includes Keras.